# How to remove date from string in "F d, Y" format?

Tags: php, regex, date, preg-replace

I need to remove all dates from a string that are in `F d, Y` format. For example, this line:

> Act current to May 30, 2015
>   Act current to June 1, 2015

Should become this:

> Act current to
>   Act current to

Here is the code I've been using:

```
$input = "Act current to May 30, 2015";
$output = preg_replace('/([January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December] [0-3]\d, \d{4})/', '', $input);
echo "$output\n";
```

The output was not what I was expecting:

> Act current to Ma
>   Act current to June 1, 2015

I believe part of my problem is that `[0-3]\d` expects the day part to be in `NN` format but that input may be in `N`.

Comment: Why do you have `[` and `]` around the month names?  Maybe `(` and `)`.

Comment: What would you expect to get from `It is expected that as of June 9, 150,000 plush "elephpants" will be roaming the planet.`?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I already wrote that very often to you, that ["Please check my answer"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274311/3933332) comments are useless and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first create an array with all month names. Then you can use this array in your regex pattern.

```
$str = "Act current to May 30, 2015"; //Act current to June 1, 2015
$months = array_map(function($v){
    return date("F", strtotime("2000-" . $v . "-1"));
}, range(1, 12));

echo $str = preg_replace("/(" . implode("|", $months) .")\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}/", "", $str);
```

regex explanation:

```
(your|months|separated|by|a|pipe)\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}/
```

- 1st Capturing group

  - One months from all of your months
- **\s** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
- **\d{1,2}** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **{1,2}** Between 1 and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **,** matches the character , literally
- **\s** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
- **\d{4}** match a digit [0-9]

  - Quantifier: **{4}** Exactly 4 times

Comment: You probably want `{1,2}` for the day of the month quantifier, or to expand it to match 1 through 31. (Aside: the OP wasn't particularly clear about only replacing *valid* dates.)

Comment: @salathe ah, yep. Completely forgot about them :) Thanks for the notice.

Comment: From your comments, I was able to get the code working by using this: $output = preg_replace('/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d{1,2}, \d{4}/', '', $input);

Comment: @WonkotheSane That is my code, only that you wrote the months by hand and changed the `\s` with spaces.

Comment: To add... I removed the \s because the dates are formatted very consistently. That said, thanks for the extra detail to explain your code. If I do come across other variations I will know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in regex in part as you suggest, this regex will work for you:

```
preg_replace('/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [1-31]+, \d{4}/', '', $input);
```